# Обработка ситуации "Данные не найдены" в Postgesql

Tags: postgresql, исключения, plpgsql

Не могу никак выйти на исключение в функции, хотя данных заведомо нет.
Код:

```
create table t
(
    id int,
    val int
);

insert into t
values
(1, 1);

-- select * from t;

-- Запрос не возвращает запись
select * from t
where id = 100;

create or replace function f() returns int as
$$
declare
    cr integer;
begin
    select val into cr
    from t
    where id = 100;
    
    return cr;
exception
    when no_data_found then
        return -1;
end
$$
language plpgsql;

select f();
```

Возвращает null, а не -1. Что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как можно уточнить [в документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW), `select val into cr` не генерирует ошибку. Это штатная ситуация. Нет ошибки - нечего ловить в обработке ошибок.

```
select val into strict cr
```

В строгом режиме будет сгенерирована ошибка.

---

Не рекомендую в `pl/pgsql` злоупотреблять исключениями. Они под капотом опираются на весьма не бесплатные savepoints, и, что особенно важно, не бесплатные не только при получении ошибки, а замедляющие работу всегда.

Можно написать, например,

```
create or replace function f() returns int as
$$
declare
    cr integer;
begin
    select val into cr
    from t
    where id = 100;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        return -1;
    END IF;
    return cr;
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Спасибо, учту обязательно. Не знал, что такие глобальные отличия от pl/sql

Comment: И еще вопрос, если можно. А общие ошибки (нарушение ограничения  и прочие) без exception никак же не обработать?

Comment: Верно. `глобальные отличия от pl/sql` опыт особенностей конкретной субд не переносим на другие субд. Особенно хранимых процедур.

Comment: а по поводу обработки общих ошибок (мой комментарий вверху) все-таки нужно пользоваться exception?

Comment: "верно" относилось именно к этому